# このカラースキームの名前を教えてください

Tags: vscode

[image: YouTubeでGo言語を用いたサーバーの解説の動画の一節です]

「vscode deep blue colorscheme」などで検索したのですが見つかりませんでした。

Comment: この画像自体はどこから持ってきたものなのでしょうか？

Comment: [Night Owl](https://vscodethemes.com/e/sdras.night-owl) の dark mode の様な気もしますが、[Dark themes](https://vscodethemes.com/dark) から探してみると良いかもしれません。

Comment: Winter is Coming (Dark Blue)が近い気がします。